# Ambassador Edge Stack : Working with sample project but not with my project

Tags: api-gateway, angular10, ambassador

I am trying to configure Ambassador as API Gateway in my kubernates cluster locally.

Installation:

1. installed from https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/tutorials/getting-started/ both windows and Kubernetes part
2. can login with `>edgectl login --namespace=ambassador localhost` and see dashboard
3. configure with a sample project they provide from https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/tutorials/quickstart-demo/

Here is the `YML` file for deployment of demo app

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: quote
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: quote
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: quote
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: docker.io/datawire/quote:0.4.1
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
```

Everything is working as expected. Now I am trying to configure with my project. But it is not working.

So for simpler case, with keeping every configuration as the demo of `Ambassador`, I just modify from `image: docker.io/datawire/quote:0.4.1` to  `image: angularapp:latest` where this is a docker image of `Angular 10` project.

But I am getting `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure`

I spent one day with this problem. I restored my Kubernates from docker desktop app and reconfigured but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs when a mapping is valid, but the service it is pointing to cannot be reached for some reason.  Is the deployment actually running (`kubectl get deploy -A -o wide`)?  Is your angular app exposing port 8080?  8080 is a pretty common kubernetes port, but not so much in the frontend development world.  If you use `kubectl exec -it {{AMBASSADOR_POD}} -- sh` does `curl http://quote` return the expected output?

Comment: Actually it was port-related problem. I made containerPort 80 and it works fine now. Thanks.